# Extrapolate using interp2d from scipy python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scipy

I am trying to 2d extrapolate with the scipy package such as :

```
interp2d(df['maturity'], df['strike'], df['IV'], fill_value='extrapolate')(0.08, 0.65)
```

the minimum value of df['maturity'] is 0.09 and I get the following error:

```
    IV = interp2d(group['maturity'], group['strike'], group['IV'], fill_value='extrapolate')(0.08, 0.65)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 298, in __call__
    z[:, out_of_bounds_x] = self.fill_value
ValueError: could not convert string to float: extrapolate
```

the fill_value='extrapolate' works perfectly on the interp1d... any idea if there is an easy way to extrapolate on the 2d method?

thanks.

Comment: it's moaning about string values so what are the dtypes here? what does `df.info()` show?

Comment: `code <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
date           72 non-null datetime64[ns]
IV             72 non-null float64
maturity       72 non-null float64
strike         72 non-null float64` the problems seems to come from the fact that it uses  z[:, out_of_bounds_x] = self.fill_value and try to pass a string somehow. In fact I think it try to pass both values like this :(0.08, 0.65) and see it has a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I did not do my home work.

```
fill_value = 'extrapolate'
```

only works for interp1d. if you don't give interp2d a fill_value param, it will extrapolate.